# Discord.JS v13 start typing and stop typing

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I simulate typing in **Discord.JS v13** ex: *Bot is typing..* I know, that in Discord.JS v12 you can just easily use **msg.channel.startTyping()** or **msg.channel.stopTyping()**, but i didn't found any result, that works on v13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use: `<channel>.sendTyping()`

This method automatically stops typing after 10 seconds, or when a message is sent.

Example of usage:

```js
await message.channel.sendTyping();
await message.channel.send("Hello World!");
```

Comment: and can I stop it manually?

Comment: startTyping(), stopTyping() have both been replaced by a singular `<TextChannel>.sendTyping()`

Comment: @abdooo9 stopTyping() was removed completely. The only ways to stop typing are sending a message or waiting a bit

Comment: @MrMythical I said that :)

Comment: So, Did this work for you? @jihndoc

Comment: @jihndoc
 I would really appreciate it if you would accept my answer :-), Just click on the grey checkmark.

Comment: Sure, I forgot.